# Finding the basis for the row space of matrix $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A = \begin{bmatrix}0&0&1&-3&2\\2&-1&4&2&1\\4&-2&9&1&4\\2&-1&5&-1&5\end{bmatrix}$, after I perform row-reduction, I get $U=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&4&2&1\\0&0&1&-3&2\\0&0&0&0&2\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I can see that there are pivots in rows 1, 2 and 3 of $U$. So I thought the basis for the row space of $A$ would be ${(2, -1, 4, 2, 1), (0, 0, 1, -3, 2), (0, 0, 0, 0, 2)}$

Because I had to exchange the rows of $A$ using $P=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$to obtain $U$, the pivots are not in rows 1, 2, and 3 of $A$ but instead in rows 1, 2 and 4. So the basis for the row space would be $(0, 0, 1, -3, 2), (2, -1, 4, 2,1), (2, -1, 5, -1, 5)$

So now I have 2 sets of bases, and my question is which set is correct? Or are both correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$(2,-1,5,-1,5)=(2,−1,4,2,1)+(0,0,1,−3,2)+(0,0,0,0,2),$$ and conversely $$(0,0,0,0,2)=(2,-1,5,-1,5)-(2,−1,4,2,1)-(0,0,1,−3,2)$$ so both sets span the same vector space.

Comment: So if I put down either set of basis on the test it would be correct?

Comment: Yes. If your row reduction was correct of course.

Comment: @Adrian it is customary to accept an answer if you're satisfied with it. If you need more help, please ask.